# While clicking add new page in wordpress admin style breaks

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress admin while clicking add new page the style breaks on loading and then it appears.

Herewith attached link for screenshot https://prnt.sc/nazit8

Also I have tried these below 2 steps

Open up your WP-config.php file and insert the code

```
define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true );
```

and in wp-admin/load-styles.php

```
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to plugin conflict. When I deactivated the plugins it works well.